# best pratice about observable

Tags: angular, observable

I have a working code but that is not written in the best way according to the canons of reactive programming.

As you can see in the code, I need to use the data that the observable returns to me.

Don't give much consideration to what the for loops do, I just need to use the data that the observable returns  to me.

If I run the for loops outside of the subscription, it is possible that the data I need is not yet available, so I cannot follow this path.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.subscriptionGetRating = this.ratingService.getRating(this.userId).subscribe({ 

      next:data => {

        this.count = data['count'];
        this.rating = data['rating'] / this.count;

        if(this.count == 0){

          this.rating = 0;

          for(let k=0;k<=4;k++){
            this.ratingArray[k] = this.greyStar;
          }

        } else{

          let trunc = Math.trunc(this.rating);

          for(let j=0;j<trunc+1;j++){

            if(this.rating>j && this.rating<j+1){
              this.ratingArray[j] = this.midStar;
            }else {
              if(j!=trunc)
                this.ratingArray[j] = this.yellowStar;
            }

          }

          if (this.rating == Math.floor(this.rating)){
            for(let k=trunc;k<=4;k++){
              this.ratingArray[k] = this.greyStar;
            }
          } else {
            for(let k=trunc+1;k<=4;k++){
              this.ratingArray[k] = this.greyStar;
            }
          }

        }

      },

      error:error => {
        console.error(error);
      }

    });

}
```

I wish some good soul gives me at least one example of how I can solve this problem.

Reading on the net I found only examples where the only operation that is performed is to print in the console the data that the observable returns (`console.log(data);`).

Comment: It would help if you would show how this is called and why other data might not yet be available yet.

Comment: hi thanks for reply. It is ngOnInit() so it is called on the initialization of component. Data could not be avaiable yes becouse this.ratingService.getRating is asyncronous, it call an HTTP GET request

Comment: The question is *why* is it a problem? What's trying to use the data that might not be available? All of the code in your example is dealing with the result inside the subscribe, so I'm not sure what's not available?

Comment: "it is possible that the data I need is not yet available" - what does this mean?

Comment: I said " If I run the for loops outside of the subscription, it is possible that the data I need is not yet available".

Comment: Hi I can suggest you to use pipe operator and use map function for transforming your data

Comment: OK. Well this is really just asking for an opinion about how to refactor your example rather than dealing with a specific problem. We could be here all day.

Comment: @RahulTokase I don't trasform my data in this example

Comment: @KurtHamilton can u suggest me something about my problem? keywords for search, or tutorial?

Comment: @RahulTokase I reconsidered your suggestion. Are you telling me that I have to use operators to assign date values to variables and perform for loops operations with operators also?

Comment: @canerandagio What techniques you use depends on what your use case is. RxJS is a massive subject that is very powerful, but you need to be able to define what your problem is before you can fix it

Comment: If I understand you right, your problem is that you want to use this data out of subscribe block. If that is the case, there is no one single answer to this. You just have to do more research about how to consume async resources and over time, you will start thinking whole app in an async way.

Comment: @s.alem thanks for reply. I don't find anything useful in solving my problem with those keywords. unless the solution uses async await. Anyway now I have transformed the code with toPromise, I think it's a better approach than the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get more clear and redable code you can use following code (I assume that getRating send one request and you need to wait for response)

```js
try {
  let data = await this.ratingService.getRating(this.userId).toPromise();
  // here process data using if/for
} catch(e) { 
  // handle error here
}
```

dont forget to add keyword `async` before `ngOnInit()`. If you don't want to handle errors then remove try-catch - then your code be even simpler (less nested). Async/await construction is designed to remove asynchronous code complexity (nest). Using it your code looks more like typical synchronous code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I accepted your answer but is it possible to process the datas in for loops by rxjs operators?

Comment: @canerandagio probably, yes - but I never seen more clean construction than async/await + Promise (don't think that it is "step back" - is not true - "Simplicity is the Ultimate Sophistication" ~Leonardo da Vinci). Of course if you have more requests and more complicate synchronisation rules then observable can be better choice.

Answer (score 3):

1: this.ratingService.getRating(this.userId).pipe(
map(
 data => {
  HANDLE DATA HERE
}));

2: try to minimise using Subscription in TS file use A pipe(map()) to return it observable

2.1: try reading into the different kind of maps in the rxjs library https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

3: Iff you want to use an observable use async pipe in html file

4: Iff you use a subscription always unsubscribe in ngondestroy.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for this kind of order:

```
this.obs.subscribe(
  val => { console.log(val) },                 //next callback
  error => { console.log("error") },           //error callback
  () => { console.log("Completed") }           //complete callback
)
```

Ok, so you said you need to do a for loop inside an observable, the question  is why?, but if you have to. You can use the operator  pipe and then map the items  to do something like this code:

iAmAnObservable
    .pipe(
       map(value => value.item),//--> for iterate  values in the observable, helps you out with changes  in the data.
       take(1),//--> is for use a part of the array only
       takeUntil(this._destroyed$)
    );

But seriously talking, it's  not a good practice, use logic in the components, and in the front  end actually, you need try to do all operations  in back end and just inject  the result  to the angular  app, if you want too see best practices  for angular  in general  i recommend  this link:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/best-practices-for-a-clean-and-performant-angular-application-288e7b39eb6f/

Comment: No, i m want to know what is the best pratice to write the for loops in the observer. It is not a beast pratice what i did. Kamil answer is right. Thanks for interest.

Comment: This is the better, more syntactically correct, way to write observable patterns. Not sure why the accepted answer is using async await pattern when the question is about observable best practices...